# How to install mapbox search properly?

Tags: ios, mapbox, mapbox-ios

I'm trying to install Mapbox on Xcode 14.1 with swift package manager.

Installing Mapbox maps is OK, but when I try to install Mapbox search, it fails despite I respected [installation instructions](https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/search/guides/install/).

Here is the error :

[image]

Tried to install another version (beta.21) but same error.

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score -1):

I guess XCode have problems with spm lately try with Cocoapods

```
pod 'MapboxSearchUI', ">= 1.0.0-beta.39", "< 2.0"
```